# My code works, But how do I make this code run in a deterministic time?

Tags: python, algorithm, performance

**The Problem: 
Given 3 inputs Bounce, Ball drop height, and ball view height.**

How do I calculate the number of times the observer can see the ball pass. 
So my code gives correct output, but it takes a longer time as bounce approaches 1, how do I make it deterministic in nature.

```
def bouncingBall(h, bounce, window):
    BounceFactor = bounce
    BallDropHeight = h
    ViewerHeight = window
    BounceLeft = h
    BallSeenTimes = 1
    if bounce > 1 or bounce < 0 or window >= h or h ==0:

        return -1
    else:
        while (BounceLeft > ViewerHeight):
            BounceLeft = BounceLeft * BounceFactor
            if (BounceLeft > ViewerHeight):
                BallSeenTimes = BallSeenTimes + 2
            else:
                break
        return BallSeenTimes
```

*I am not looking for code answers, just the direction in which I need to think.
Currently, I think If I could somehow establish a linear relationship and create a function to "guess" the passes it would be faster.*

Comment: Turn the problem into an equation, solve for your variable, then plug in the other inputs.

Comment: Next H = Initial H x BounceFactor, This gives me a rate of change of the height, but how do I calculate all such "Next H", without actually doing it. Any hints?

Comment: That must be something like NextH₂ = (Initial H x BounceFactor x BounceFactor). It even works with BounceFactors > 1! (But not < 0.)

Comment: Bounce factor greater than 1 would be problematic as it would never cease. Solution would become infinite. So improbable case.

Comment: Cross-posted at [Computer Science Stack Exchange](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/100069/my-code-works-but-how-do-i-make-this-code-run-in-a-deterministic-time). I recommend this post be deleted.

Comment: Back to physics: `d = (1/2)*a*t^2`. In this case, d = ViewerHeight (I think; variable names could be a little more clear). a = BounceFactor. You're solving for t, which in your function is BallSeenTimes. In short, BallSeenTimes = math.sqrt(2 * ViewerHeight / BounceFactor). Times two, I think, because you're incremending BallSeenTimes by two each time.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how much this is right. But,

`var heightDiff = (BallDropHeight - ViewerHeight);
 var reducedHeight = BallDropHeight *(1 - BounceFactor);
 var BallSeenTimes = ((heightDiff/reducedLength)*2)+1;`

may actually solve it. You just need to find the height reduced on each bounce. Then dividing the height difference between viewer and ball drop point with the reducedHeight will give the number of times ball bounced above the viewer. After that, multiplying with 2 is for each bounce viewer will see it twice. And adding one is for the first time drop.

There is no loop involved in it. So, the time taken to execute will be small only. Hopefully, it helps.!